# Delete a specific dimen value in all dimen folders in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-plugin

How can I delete a specific dimen value in all dimen folders in Android. Is there a faster way to do it rather than manually deleting in each places.
I know I can use the searching tool in android studio but what if I need to delete more than 100 values, and each of them is located in so many folders (values-sw330dp, values-sw360dp, values-sw390dp, ect)

Answer (score 0):

try removing all its usages from the project & removing unused resources from the `Refractor -> Remove unused resources` menu option.